# Goto declaration that mimics the "Goto event handler" behavior

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, editor, vsix

I wish to mimic the "Navigate to Event Handler" behavior to "Goto declaration".

Meaning, when you right click on property, you get an option to goto declaration from the view (xmal) to it's declaration (cs/dll)

For example,
Given next xaml:

```
<Button Content="New" Command="{Binding Path=NewCommand}" />
```

Right click on "*Command*" with take me to code (from metadata) of "*ButtonBase.Command*".
Right click on "*NewCommand*" will take me to "*NewCommand*" property on my View-Model code.

I have tried [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885242.aspx), but noting is close to it.

Thanks,
Ofir

Answer (score 0):

The kind of functionality you are looking for does not come with visual studio out-of-the-box. However, you might find a third-party add-on that gives you what you want. For example, ReSharper adds improved [navigation and search](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/xaml_editor.html#Navigation_and_Search), allowing you to navigate to a property declaration from XAML. I doubt it works for binding Paths though because it would need to know what your `DataContext` is.

Comment: Thanks Colin.
I'm aiming to implement it with VS2010 editor extension project (vsix).
I wish to retrieve the `DataContext` as well.